# Aspect Oriented Development/Programming resource

Tags: asp.net, aop, design-patterns

Recently, I've had a request to implement logging for all of the Controller classes in my ASP.NET project.  I've used postsharp and everything is working great!  But, usual question: is there any OpenSource component or any pattern?    Also, I want to know more about AOP design patterns, resources and real-world application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Spring.NET AOP](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html) features with NHibernate to implement automatic SQL transaction commit/rollback. Depending on how those *Controller classes* are implemented in your ASP.NET application this might or not be a viable option. Sometimes a custom [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) is sufficient.

Comment: I want to have the facility if I set the the application running in debug mode (web.config), the logger logs all methods in controller with method execution duration.

Comment: I would like to know if you achieved this already, and how, please, thank you!

Comment: @Luis Lobo Borobia, yes I have. Everything that's needed is perfectly covered in the [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate). If you encounter some specific problems don't hesitate to start a new question explaining what exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you tried so far that didn't work.